# Simple example to understand vectorisation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I am trying to understand how vectorisation works in pandas dataframes.

Let's take this dataframe as example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

And let's say I want to add a new column `flag` with value 0 if the entry of the first column is below the `df.mean()` value and value 1 otherwise.
The result would be:

```
df["flag"] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Could anyone explain me how to apply this element wise check to the dataframe and what would be the difference compared to using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write the comparison and pandas will take care of the rest.
Take a look at this:

```py
mean_val = df[0].mean() # The mean of your first column
df["flag"] = (df[0] >= mean_val).astype(int)
# the 'astype(int)' is used to get 1/0 instead of True/False
```

The advantages of doing this are:

1. Simpler to read and write.
2. Pandas can do many optimizations since it knows it will be doing element-wise comparison instead of a generic loop.

Comment: Many thanks.. How should I modify the inequality if I want to have some multiple equality, such as if value > (mean + std) then 1, if value < (mean - std) then -1, else 0?

Comment: The method I showed above is useful when looking for a True/False result, for that you could use the `apply` method such as:
```df["flag_2"] = df[0].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > mean + std else -1 if x < (mean - std) else 0)```